# How to get a list of ActiveRecord objects by frequency based on a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord scope method in my Recipe model that looks like this.

```
scope :most_popular, -> { joins(:user_recipes).group(:recipe_id).count }
```

Which returns a hash containing the `recipe_id => frequency` based on the number of times the recipe appears in the user_recipes join table.

What I'd really like is to get the actual recipe object in place of the recipe_id so that I don't have to query the database again when displaying in my view.  I've tried most everything I can think of.  I feel like this should be straightforward but I'm missing some small detail.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that

```
scope :most_popular, -> { joins(:user_recipes).group(:recipe_id).order('count(recipe_id) desc') }
```

Should do what you want

Comment: This does return me the recipe objects that I was looking for but not the count of each recipe item, unfortunately.  Essentially I'd like it in the format I got it in before but instead of `recipe_id => count` I'd like `recipe => count`

Comment: @SYoung82 what you're asking for isn't possible with a hash, but you could do it with an array. So something like `[[ recipe_1, count ], [ recipe_2, count ] ]`

Comment: @mmichael that would work too I suppose, any suggestions on how exactly to do it?

Comment: @SYoung82 there are a number of ways you can do this (e.g. using `map`) and it depends on how performant you want the query to be. If you're working with a large collection of Recipes, then mapping (iterating) through them all will be very expensive. By the way, it's certainly possible to set an AR object as a hash key with a value, just not (AFAIK) through a query alone.

Comment: @mmichael, thanks a bunch, you've got me pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I'm not near a database right now but try adding `.select('recipes.*, count(recipe_id)  as user_count')` you should be able to access the attribute as `recipe.attributes['user_count']`